# Merge into table with 'with' statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, sql-merge

I need to update or insert to table range of dates with some data. For example, I get `startDate = 01/01/2022` and `endDate = 01/01/2023`, and I need to add 365 rows on this table or update the relevant rows in the table.

I tried to do this, but it's not working and I get an error:

> SQL Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.

Code:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_DATE
USING 
WITH ListDates(AllDates) AS
(SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,'2017-03-05') AS DATE
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,AllDates)
  FROM ListDates 
  WHERE AllDates < DATEADD(DAY,-1,'2017-04-11'))
 SELECT AllDates
 FROM ListDates) as b
 ON (B.DD = TABLE_DATE.DATE)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET TABLE_DATE.ccc = 100
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 INSERT (ID, DATE, ccc) VALUES (1, B.DD, 100);
```

Comment: You can't nest a CTE inside a Merge statement like that afaik, the CTE must be defined first and then referenced. `Merge` has many issues it's best to simply outer join to your CTE and `update`, followed by a separate `insert`.

Comment: do you have another idea how to select range of dates without 'with'? in oracle I did it like this: 
SELECT DT + (LEVEL - 1) DD 
 FROM (SELECT DATE '2017-03-05' DT FROM DUAL)
 CONNECT BY DT + (LEVEL-1) <= DATE '2017-04-11'

Comment: You can still use your recursive CTE if you want to and reference it - better though would be to utilise a permanent *calendar table*. You'd have the same issue in Oracle I believe where you would just replace the derived query after `from` with the name of the CTE.

Comment: can you give me example how to do it with calander table?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your data, but the following is reported as valid syntax. Generally speaking, with SQL Server, place your CTE first:

```
 WITH ListDates(AllDates)
      AS (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2017-03-05') AS DATE
          UNION ALL
          SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, AllDates)
            FROM ListDates
           WHERE AllDates < DATEADD(DAY, -1, '2017-04-11'))
 
      MERGE INTO TABLE_DATE
      USING (
      SELECT AllDates
        FROM ListDates ) AS b
      ON(B.DD = TABLE_DATE.DATE)
        WHEN MATCHED
            THEN UPDATE SET
                            TABLE_DATE.ccc = 100
        WHEN NOT MATCHED
            THEN
            INSERT(ID
                 , DATE
                 , ccc)
            VALUES ( 1 , B.DD , 100 );
```